# Low conversion performance for toJS(Immutable)

Tags: javascript, react-redux, immutable.js

```
let dataSource = Immutable.fromJS( {peple: {age: 18, preferences:['basketball', 'football']}}} ); let jsObj = dataSource.toJS()
```

I'm using redux, which is very time-consuming for TOJS conversions, especially on some hardware devices.
For example, sometimes it can take 1 seconds or more.
**I want to know if Imuutable has an API that can use immutable data directly in JavaScript.**

Comment: I am accustomed to using JavaScript objects or arrays to render the view, can I use immutable data to render the view? I don't know much about immutable data API.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to convert it? If your state is already represented as an immutable collection why not keep it as it is and access data via `get` methods from `Map/List` API. If you want to change your state you can just call `push/set` function which will return a new instance of the immutable collection (with updated data).

Comment: I'd rephrase in the form of an answer before some pedant flags this as "not an answer." "Don't convert to plain JS" is a great response to this question.